Javafx WebView is not able to show pages of geoportal.ch correctly (tested with javafx 22, javafx 17.10)
its not about google maps, all pages containing any kind of map visualisation are not showing these. But how specifically show the content of geoportal.ch? A bunch of pages not working:
geoportal.ch
or
google maps
or
openstreetmaps
these pages are not usable as the maps are missing.
Why is it not possible to show a page with maps - specifically geoportal.ch - with Javafx Webview Component? And how to enhance/correct so its works as expected?
My examinations: Other questions answers are saying for the google-maps case they changed their api from a certain javafx version. Well why should they (it was working before...)? If for any reason that was true, why do other pages not showing maps either. SwingNode in combination with jcef does also not work or kept secret.
So in the end it looks like the only solution is to buy proprietary software...  whats going wrong here? The web is most crucial - having a half way working Javafx-Webview Component is just strange. That for years. But its not about google maps, its about a immature webview component. Maybe one sees why maps are not showed in general.
I enabled com.sun.webkit.WebPage.level = FINE for logging which does not give me a solution how to solve it.
Demoapplication:
package com.example.webviewsample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        TextField urlField = new TextField("https://www.geoportal.ch/ch/map/40?y=2683332.00&x=1247089.90&scale=2000&rotation=0&topic=property&highlight=1&bfsnr=3203&property=W7391");
        Button goButton = new Button("Go");

        goButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            String url = urlField.getText();
            webEngine.load(url);
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(urlField);
        root.setCenter(webView);
        root.setBottom(goButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("WebView Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


This may clear some stuff up???

Gluon Maps provides an API for showing maps based on OpenStreetMaps data, which (as I understand it) is not webview based.

Yes Gluon has a Map Component. Which thouhg is only working for OpenStreetMaps.. not any pages with maps.

SedJ601. No, it does not really as it covers google maps. And as written, changing the userAgent should avoid that if it was a problem with google. Which i wrote is not the only problem. Any page with maps is not working.

My thought is that per the link, neither JavaFX nor Google officially support each other. To me this means things may break or not work given that the two are not on the same page and change things up sometimes. I can only assume that the same thing holds true for the other two map technologies you mentioned.

Google Maps display (currently) with JavaFX 18 as noted in the duplicate.  I also tried geoportal.ch link from your question with JavaFX 18, but that did not display.  Perhaps this is not a duplicate, as you are referencing multiple map technologies (I can unmark it as duplicate if preferred).  But I think the marked duplicate answers your second main question "how to enhance/correct so its works as expected?" -> use JavaFX 18 and Google Maps.

"changing the userAgent should avoid that if it was a problem with google" -> There is much more to rendering a map than setting the user agent string.  The user agent itself needs to be innately capable of rendering the map, and that is not the case (currently) with JavaFX > 18 and Google Maps.  Also as you note: "if all pages with maps are not working its more probably an issue with the Webview component" -> this is true, it could also have been an issue with the Google implementation, but in this case it is an issue with WebView capabilities.

Well i think its not a duplicate rather its a bug of WebView in the end. Maybe someone will know and take care of that. It was working for google maps before and as you say with 18. Than from one day to another it stopped working. For sure not because of google changes in their api. They must have implemented a check if its not version 18.. did they? Probably not. So, again, its WebView in the end. So, stucked with an old 1.8 version or just 18.But 18 lacks of other issues etc., which also is not usable in my case.WebView: In my mind comes that its on purpose not to have a workable component

"They must have implemented a check if its not version 18.. did they?" -> Almost certainly not.  They don't officially support JavaFX WebView as a client, so I doubt they would add some kind of block like that.  On the other hand, it is known from investigations mentioned in the related question that Google Maps currently works in 18 and not 18.0.1+ and that the WebKit version in JavaFX was changed between those two versions.  So the change in WebKit version or the JavaFX interface to it is what is currently causing Google Maps to fail in later JavaFX versions.

"So, stucked with an old 1.8 version or just 18.But 18 lacks of other issues etc., which also is not usable in my case.WebView: In my mind comes that its on purpose not to have a workable component" -> given your stated requirements, I agree with you. If you are interested in pursuing trying to get the JavaFX WebView fixed so that it can support Google Maps in future versions, you might wish to bring the matter up with the JavaFX developers on the openjfx-dev mailing list.

As you don't believe this is a duplicate of JavaFX not embedding google maps html, which is an understandable point of view, I removed the duplicate marker and reopened the question, so that answers could be added if one becomes available in the future.

It was working with Version JDK8u411 and jfx18 only. So in the end its a bug of the webview component. I fulfilled a bug-report which you can now find officially here:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8331640
